# Concatenating an Android's string resource with a hard-coded string

Tags: java, android, string

I am working in an Android project in which I created a string resource in the *values/strings.xml* file. Let's say this is the string:

```
<string name="some_text">HELLO WORLD</string>
```

I can call this string from anywhere inside my project like so:

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                R.string.some_text,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This generates a Toast with the text "HELLO WORLD" in it.

But if I try to concatenate this string with some hard-coded text like this:

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                R.string.some_text + String.valueOf(123),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I get this nasty result:

"**2131368234234** 123"

instead of:

"**HELLO WORLD** 123".

Does someone know what is happening here?

Thanks

Comment: R.string.some_text is an integer not a string. Use String.valueof function or any appropriate function to decode that integer to the string it points at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does someone know what is happening here?

You are concatenating an integer (`R.string.some_text`) with a `String` (`String.valueOf(123)`).

Use `getString(R.string.some_text)` to get the `String` that is the appropriate value for this resource for the current configuration.

Comment: Oh, I forgot R.string.some_text was an integer, not a string. Thanks CommonsWare, smooth as silk!